# Python If statement equal string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want `jobber()` to do the following: if user inputs "talk" it runs `chat()` and "calc" for `calculator()`.

This is my very first project and I am completely new so thanks for any help.

```
import sys
import time
def chat():
    print('Hello there. What is your name?')
    name = sys.stdin.readline()
    print('Your name is %s...interesting. My name is Chat I was created to have a small planned out conversation when you call me :)' % (name))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('How is the weather in your town today?')
    weather = sys.stdin.readline()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print('Your weather is %s? The weather in my town is quite sunny.' % (weather))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('This is all the conversation I can make at the moment. Please be patient while my creator trys to update me.')


def calculator():
    print('How much money do you have?')
    money = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    print('How much are you paid?')
    job = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    print('How much do you usually spend?')
    spent = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    for week in range(0,30):
            money = money + job - spent
            print('Week %s. Money %s' % (week,money))



def jobber():
    print('Type talk for a short chat. Type calc for a money calculator.')
    choice = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    if choice == 1:
            chat()
    if choice == 2:
            calculator()
```

Comment: what is your problem, what does not work? what help do you need?

Comment: So where do you ever call `jobber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `input()` and convert to `lowercase`

```
def jobber():
     choice = input('Type talk for a short chat. Type calc for a money calculator.').lower()
    if choice == "talk":
            chat()
    if choice == "calc":
            calculator()
```

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't exist in python 3.

Comment: Thanks this helps. I'm still learning python right now so that would explain why I haven't tried that. This was really just a test to see what I could do with what I'd already learned.

Answer (score 0):

For gathering user input, you'd better use input() function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) built in function, for example setting the `money` variable in the `calculate` function should simply be:

```
money = int(input('How much money do you have?'))
```

Since you are only using the `choice` variable to determine which function to perform, you can even consider placing the input in the if statement:

```
if input('Type talk or chat.') == 'calc':
    calculator()
else:
    chat()
```

The [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) is a good guide as to how use if statements and other control flow tools.

Comment: Or even better a `dict`-dispatch: `{'calc': calculator, 'talk': chat}[choice]()`, then at least if it's not valid, you'd get an exception